# How to specify Excel default proxy when streaming Excel via VCS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, powerpivot

I would like to using Excel with PowerPivot to read data from an SSRS report. When I try and access the report using atomsvc, the connection works fine, but I get the error: "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

Some [googling](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cd5c7877-b7e4-4041-a1d6-feaa33e5e74e/powerpivot-datamarket-place-and-proxy-authentication%20) showed me that I need to use a config file (Excel.exe.config) placed in the same directory as Excel.exe to tell Excel to use the defaultcredentials, my problem is that the company I'm working at uses thin clients and [VCS](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/mdop/appv-v5/deploying-microsoft-office-2013-by-using-app-v), so Excel with Powerpivot is not present on my machine, it is instead streamed from a server on launch.

Is there any other way to specify the configuration credentials to Excel? I've tried startup switches, but there doesn't seem to be one to specify this. Perhaps there is a way to configure the streamed application on the VCS side? My alternative is to tap into the SSRS Web Service, but that would be a lot more work, and more complex for whomever supports this after me. Another option could be to add a registry entry?

Comment: Not sure if this would be better asked on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com)

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I get any help here and if not will transfer it over.